# How to create webview in apache cordova for all platforms

Tags: apache, cordova, visual-studio-2013, webview

I want to create an mobile webview application in Apache Cordova using Visual Studio 2013; also, I want to handle features of mobile like camera,back button.

I have gone through the following Apache Cordova documentation:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_webviews_index.md.html

According to this link ,3 different webviews need to be created but I want to know whether it is possible to create ***just*** one webview which will support Windows phone, Android and iPhone?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking if you can code once and deploy in all three platforms?

Comment: what you ask isn't possible, every OS have it's own webview. Anyway you don't have to worry about the webview, just create a cordova project and it will manage to create the webview for you. The link you provide is for integrating the cordova webview on existing native projects

Comment: thank u for your comments! Actually i am asking is it possible to create only one webview in cordova application and deploy in all three platforms?  Will cordova manage to handle my webview in all three os?

Comment: @jcesarmobile: i didnt understand what does this means:just create a cordova project and it will manage to create the webview for you. Does this means that i should create a webview application in cordova and the cordova will manage to handle os compatibility?

Comment: that means you create a cordova project and don't worry about the webviews being created. Cordova will use the native webview for each platform, you just have to worry about the webview support for the html5 features you want to use, not every webview supports the same things

Answer (score 0):

The embedded webview you're referring to is really a special case where you want to have a Cordova-based webview inside of a native app. Is that what you really want to do? If you just want to build a normal Cordova app that will run on your three platforms it's easily doable, just follow the instructions here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html